# Remove holes from polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, donut-polygons

There are several answers for this question on GIS stackexchange but none using open/free software.

How can someone without access to the Esri suite remove interior holes from a polygon?

Example data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K9JanJe79d6wqf1v7hjBkGSfHcL1q6qN?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so i took the data given by Hugh_Kelley and i was able to find a good postgis solution.

I imported both shapefiles in PostgresSql and used this query.

I expected to find a lot of polygons with holes but it was mainly multi geometry as you can see on the picture.

```
CREATE TABLE public.result_union as (
SELECT St_SetSrid( ST_MakePolygon (St_ExteriorRing( St_union( (polys.geom)))),27700) AS poly_boundary
from polys)
```

With this query, I found the same geometry as the boundary shapefile given by Hugh.

[image]

The St_exteriorRing function only accept polygon, so you can not just St_Collect them.

You really need to do a St_Union to dissolve the boundary and if it gives back a MultiGeometrie which is possible, you will have to dump it with St_Dump and do a St_ExteriorRing on each part.

The performance here was ok , 13 secondes , but with the union involved,
I suspect it can be hard to use this on a very high number of geometry.

Comment: This is great, I think `ST_Dump`ing the multipolygon and calling `ST_ExteriorRing` on each part was where I switched to QGIS. I'll apply it to the ~4500 polygons in the entirety of London and see how performance is.

Answer (score 2):

This may be possible to do in PostGIS using `ST_Dump` but when I tried I got an error saying:

```
Can't resolve struct type geometry_dump
```

A search for the error seemed to indicate that this meant that PostGIS wasn't installed correctly, but that seems unlikely in my case. I never resolved this error.

Instead I used QGIS, which is easily connected to a PostgreSQL database.

There is a `Delete Holes` function you can find by searching in the processing toolbox.

[image: processing toolbox search]

Comment: I would suggest you to look into Postgis Function and a combo of St_ExteriorRing with St_polygonize may do the trick. i'll try to make an answer with it later

Comment: yeah I explored that combination yesterday actually, because it's supposed to do exactly that, but `ST_ExteriorRing` just returned `NULL`. Looking at the docs, maybe this was because the geometry was a multipolygon rather than a polygon. Then given the trouble converting to type `polygon` with `ST_Dump` a solution didn't seem likely.

Comment: `polygon` isn't a PostGIS type. It's the native (and moderately useless) geometry type. Your Answer is a Question in disguise. I suggest you rewrite the question to focus on this issue so it can be answered.

Comment: Can you share your data ? i will give it a shot if you can share it

Comment: fair enough, QGIS works perfectly well and it's available to all but happy to help find a solution in postgis too.  Added a link to a folder with the data. `polys.shp` is the raw data and `boundary.shp` is the required outcome.