# Remove/Fill holes in Polygons from a MultiPolygon using JTS Topology Suite programmatically

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite

There are several questions/answers using ERIS,etc. 
like:
[Remove holes from polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330733/remove-holes-from-polygon)

But I am having a challenge applying the solution programmatically using the JTS Topology suite only.

Below is an example of MultiPolygon.. I want to remove/fill the holes.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a new `Polygon` from the `ExteriorRing` of the input `Polygon`.

```
gf.createPolygon(p.getExteriorRing().getCoordinateSequence());
```

There is a little more work with `MultiPolygon`s as you have to handle each subpolygon in turn. The whole method becomes something like:

```
  static GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
  static public Geometry removeHoles(Geometry g) {

    if (g.getGeometryType().equalsIgnoreCase("Polygon")) {
      Polygon p = (Polygon) g;
      return gf.createPolygon(p.getExteriorRing().getCoordinateSequence());
    } else if (g.getGeometryType().equalsIgnoreCase("MultiPolygon")) {

      MultiPolygon mp = (MultiPolygon) g;
      List<Polygon> polys = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < mp.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
        Polygon poly = gf.createPolygon(((Polygon) mp.getGeometryN(i)).getExteriorRing().getCoordinateSequence());
        polys.add(poly);
      }
      return gf.createMultiPolygon(polys.toArray(new Polygon[] {}));

    }

    return g;
  }
```

Comment: Yup. Thanks I did just that.

Answer (score 6):

OpenJUMP has a "remove holes" tool (and an advanced "remove small holes" tool as well). OpenJUMP often uses JTS rather directly but I am not sure about this case. The source code of the function is at https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/core/trunk/src/com/vividsolutions/jump/workbench/ui/plugin/analysis/GeometryFunction.java

The idea seems to be simple: Get the list of polygons, get the exterior rings and create new polygons from those. Inner rings disappear and job is done.

```
  // added on 2016-11-11 by mmichaud
  private static class RemoveHolesFunction extends GeometryFunction {
    public RemoveHolesFunction() {
      super(I18N.get("ui.plugin.analysis.GeometryFunction.Remove-Holes"), 1, 0);
    }

    public Geometry execute(Geometry[] geom, double[] param)
    {
      AbstractGeometryProcessor removeHoleProcessor = new AbstractGeometryProcessor() {
        public void process(Polygon polygon, List<Geometry> list) {
          list.add(polygon.getFactory().createPolygon((LinearRing)polygon.getExteriorRing()));
        }
      };
      return removeHoleProcessor.process(geom[0]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
/**
 * Remove holes from a Polygonal geometry
 * @param g The geometry to remove holes from
 * @param filter A filter to decide if the holes should be removed. If null removes all
 * @param <T> Geometry type
 * @return A geometry with holes removed
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static  <T extends Geometry> T removeHoles(T g, Predicate<Polygon> filter) {
    if (!g.isEmpty() && g instanceof Polygon) {
        final Polygon p = (Polygon) g;

        final GeometryFactory factory = p.getFactory();
        final List<LinearRing> interiorRings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < p.getNumInteriorRing() ; i++){
            final LineString interiorRing = p.getInteriorRingN(i);
            final LinearRing linearRing = factory.createLinearRing(interiorRing.getCoordinates());
            if(filter!=null && filter.test(factory.createPolygon(linearRing,new LinearRing[]{}))){
                interiorRings.add(linearRing);
            }
        }
        return (T) factory.createPolygon(factory.createLinearRing(p.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates()),interiorRings.toArray(new LinearRing[]{}));
    } else if (!g.isEmpty() && g instanceof MultiPolygon) {
        final MultiPolygon mp = (MultiPolygon) g;
        final ArrayList<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mp.getNumGeometries() ; i++){
            polygons.add(removeHoles((Polygon) mp.getGeometryN(i),filter));
        }
        return (T)mp.getFactory().createMultiPolygon(polygons.toArray(new Polygon[]{}));
    }

    return g;
}
```

Use it like this:

```java
//removes hole bigger than minAreaFactor
removeHoles(someGeometry, p -> p.getArea() > minAreaFactor)
```