# How to I recreate MultiPolygon with Rings/Holes using org.geojson

Tags: geojson

I have a few original MultiPolygons that contain holes...I would like to extract the Polygons and recreate them WOTHOUT the holes.  how is this done?

Original MultiPolygon.
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/978eaa4a10df9467638a5eb9259c84e6
[image]

when breaking up the Multipolygon

```
   org.geojson.MultiPolygon reCreateMultiPolygon = new org.geojson.MultiPolygon();
             for (List<List<LngLatAlt>> polygonPoints : multiPolygon.getCoordinates()) {
                for (List<LngLatAlt> point : polygonPoints) {
                    Polygon p = new Polygon(point);
                    reCreateMultiPolygon.add(p);
                }
            }
             
             String fileName2 =   saveToFileSystem(reCreateMultiPolygon);
```

The this is treating each polygon as its own polygon...I am unclear how to recreate this with the holes intact...not treat them as normal polygons.
results:/
Incorrect recreated MultiPolygon https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/89e51458e9f5509b5457f9033474bc2d
[image]

my end goal is to create a convert that does a org.geojson.MultiPolygon to rg.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonMultiPolygon   to save in Mongodb via spring data mongodb.   if this can be done via JTS,geotools,etc. thats fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the individual polygons (including the holes) then something like:

```
  MultiPolygon mp = (MultiPolygon) g;
  List<Polygon> polys = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < mp.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
    Polygon poly = (Polygon) mp.getGeometryN(i);
    polys.add(poly);
  }
```

Will give you a `List` of `Polygon`s. Note, these are JTS geometries not geojson ones.

### Update

For just the holes you need to do something like:

```
private List<Polygon> getHoles(Geometry mp) {
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    List<Polygon> holes = new ArrayList<>();
    if (mp instanceof MultiPolygon || mp instanceof Polygon) {
      for (int i = 0; i < mp.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
        Polygon poly = (Polygon) mp.getGeometryN(i);
        for (int h = 0; h < poly.getNumInteriorRing(); h++) {
          LinearRing hole = poly.getInteriorRingN(h);
          holes.add(gf.createPolygon(hole));
        }
      }
    }
    return holes;
  }
```

Comment: i want to re-create the MultiPolygon object so when saving it will contain holes.... using what you have will recreate the MultiPolygon treating holes as normal polygons.  basically how do i create a multiPolygon that will describe the 'holes'

Comment: updated question..with my end goal.

Comment: now that i can get the holes....how do i use them to make the original MultiPolygon(that contain the holes?

Comment: What do you mean? if you want the holes in the original filled - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364571/remove-fill-holes-in-polygons-from-a-multipolygon-using-jts-topology-suite-progr

Comment: Ahh my mistake I meant recreate without holes...like the original.

Comment: i was able to solve  this by taking those 'holes' and doing a Symmetric difference using the Geometry class in JTS>...this recreated the original GeoJson(with holes)